# Differents Advertising ID per users with the same Android device

Tags: android, google-play-services

I'm using the Ad ID from android and I would like to make clear if the ID is different for each user that is using the same device. For instance, if I have a tablet that is being used by 3 different users (each one with each own account), the Advertising ID will be different per user?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have tested this myself. The advertsingID has a dependency on Google Play services. It essentially uses the signed in Google Play user. As you will see in their API, they do not have any method to pull advertisingID by Google+ user or email address etc...

Also, be aware that an advertisingID may be reset by the user at any point.